# MYSQL dump and problems character encoding

Tags: mysql, character-set

I have a 2 gb old database sql backup file. The problem is that text is encoded in UTF-8. Actually this isnt the real problem. This database contains greek and english characters.

The problem is that for example greek Π letter is encoded as
`C3 90` UTF-8  which is unicode U+00D0 , clearly not Π letter. But in ISO-8859-7 D0 is Π!

This occurs almost everywhere.. Is there a fix i can apply ?Ideally i want to convert it to utf-8..

**NOTICE**
ISO8859-7 was used

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your source data contained only English and Greek characters, and was mis-exported with an ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 conversion (rather than an ISO-8859-7 to UTF-8 conversion), you can get your data back by first repeating the missed conversion the other way around, and then doing the right one.

You could use `iconv` for this (available on pretty much all Linux distributions, and on Windows via [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm)).

You'd do something like:

```
$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 < bad_dump_file.sql | \
  iconv -f ISO-8859-7 -t UTF-8 > good_dump_file.sql
```

As an example:

```
$ echo -n $'\xC3'$'\x90' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 | \
   iconv -f ISO-8859-7 -t UTF-8 | hexdump -C
00000000  ce a0                                             |Î |
00000002
```

And `0xCE 0xA0` is the right UTF-8 encoding for [Π](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03a0/index.htm).